# Make horizontal nav menu slide to show more options on click of arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a horizontal sub menu with 8 options (can't add more or it drops to a second line), but now it needs more and i want a particular effect.  I want the last option to be an arrow and the whole menu slide horizontally to the left when the arrow is clicked to show more options and a left arrow to slide back.

I have researched for a few days and have found a few examples similar, but just haven't worked in my case.  Also, alot of answers to this similar thing involved plug-ins or carousel's and I don't think those are going to work for my particular site.

Right now I have it working kind of how I want but it's not the right effect.  I'm using .hide() and .show() in my jQuery function and basically used the class: "firstSide" for the first part of the menu you can see after it drops down from the main menu, and class="slideSide" for the 2nd part.  I've also tried .slideToggle() and playing with the widths but haven't got it to work right.

This is my codepen that I've started as an example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jsegarra/pen/Ikbep)

This codepen isn't pretty but it works for this example, this is my function in it:

```
$('#arrowRight').on('click', function () {
    $('.firstSide').hide(function () {
        $('.slideSide').show();
        $('#blankSub1').show();
    });
});

$('#arrowLeft').on('click', function () {
    $('.slideSide').hide(function () {
        $('.firstSide').show();
    });
});
```

Also I have the class slideSide set so that it doesn't display along with the first part of the menu or else its all on a 2nd line which i don't want as the width of the 8 menu options is about the full width of the whole site.

```
.slideSide {
display: none;
}
```

The desired effect I want can be seen on: http://store.apple.com/us/iphone

I've tried to see how this works but have not figured it out, below is a screen shot of the menu I'm talking about on that page.

[image: apple store shop iPhone]

Any help or advise would be appreciated as I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Effect 1 on that site when not automatically moving might work, but it seems like a challenge to implement into my site.  Is there a way to dl the source from that site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04n1dfoL/).

Is this what you are looking for?

you nest a `ul` within a `div` and make use of `overflow:hidden` on the div.

Using jquery you can then implement the sliding via `margin-left`or positioning like

`position:relative; left:-100%`
and you hide the arrows as they are clicked and so the other one.

you can play around with the values to match your needs.

Comment: You can animate even the arrows being hidden(makes it look better). Its functional but UI point of view not very pretty.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for.  I originally was playing around with overflow: hidden and the slideToggle and few things, but was having trouble with it hiding that extra part of the menu. Was probably something else in my CSS tripping me up.  I'll play around with this and let you know, thanks @Anush

Comment: Yes @Anush; this is working for me for now, thanks for helping me understand the concept too.  I had seen .animate() in some examples but they mostly all toggled out of sight completely. I just need to integrate it into my other code and hope it doesn't mess with my other jQuery functions, but i'm just glad I understand this concept now.

Comment: All the best @Stan :)